# Is it good practice to call the root logger directly when using log4net?

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I'm wondering if there is any problem or technical argument against it to call the root logger of log4net directly instead of going through another logger/appender and referencing it in the root.

What I would like to do is to get the root logger directly like:

```
this._logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Root");
```

Root definition:

```
<root>
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="Root.File"/>
</root>
```

It works perfectly fine, but I'm not sure if this a good practice.

Comment: You can if you really want to access the root logger via `((Hierarchy) LogManager.GetRepository()).Root;` - note however that it implements `ILogger` and **not** `ILog`. See the [docs](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Repository_Hierarchy_RootLogger.htm) for a little more info. However I have no idea why you would want to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say bad practice as it deviates from standard usage and I can't see any benefits.

Also I am not sure if you fully understand what it is doing. Your GetLogger command is not looking for the root logger, but is actually looking for a logger **called** root. Because you do not have one defined, it will fall back to use the root logger. But if you add one called root, as below, you can see that this disables your logging.

```
<root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="Root.File"/>
</root>
<logger name="root">
    <level value="OFF" />
</logger
```